# Inspect firefox devtools extension

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've built a chrome devtools extension, and I'm now porting it to firefox. Even if the logic works perfectly, I've got a problem with styling. In Google Chrome I could just press CTRL+SHIFT+J with a devtools window focused to open a new devtools window that let me inspect my extension and the other devtools panels. Is there a similar feature for firefox? How should I debug the styling and DOM of my devtools extension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open the correct devtools console to see output from an extension script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/how-to-open-the-correct-devtools-console-to-see-output-from-an-extension-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging extension's own pages and code can be done via `about:debugging`
More info: [Debugging](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the "More info" link, the "Debugging developer tools pages and panels" was exactly what I was looking for :)  (though it's really unintuitive how it works, to be honest...)